# How can I optimize vba code for combination of numbers

Tags: excel, vba, optimization, combinations

I am working on a problem to find combinations equal to 100 with different vector length as input. The code is working fine for the small sequence but code takes a lot of time when the sequence of numbers increases. I need to reduce the time as much as I can because sometimes it takes an hour. The maximum value of vector length can be 6 & minimum increment can be 5 so the maximum we can get is 36 numbers and output of their combinations in a set of 6. Any help in the optimization of code to a minimum possible time would be great.

Here is the snap of sheet:[image]

Here is the code:

```
Sub Combinations()
Dim rRng As Range, p As Integer
Dim vElements, lrow As Long, vresult As Variant

Range("A2:A100").Clear
Call Sequence

lrow = 25

Set rRng = Range("A2", Range("A2").End(xlDown)) ' The set of numbers
p = Range("C2").Value ' How many are picked

vElements = Application.Index(Application.Transpose(rRng), 1, 0)
ReDim vresult(1 To p)
Columns("E").Resize(, p + 5).Clear
Call CombinationsNP(vElements, p, vresult, lrow, 1, 1)
Call Delrow
Call formu
Range("C27:D15000").Clear
End Sub

Sub CombinationsNP(vElements As Variant, p As Integer, vresult As Variant, lrow As Long, iElement As Integer, iIndex As Integer)
Dim i As Integer

For i = iElement To UBound(vElements)
    vresult(iIndex) = vElements(i)
    If iIndex = p Then
        lrow = lrow + 1
        Range("E" & lrow + 1).Resize(, p) = vresult
    Else
        Call CombinationsNP(vElements, p, vresult, lrow, i + 1, iIndex + 1)
    End If
Next i
End Sub

Sub Delrow()
Dim lrow As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim x As Integer

lrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 27 To lrow + 1
x = Cells(i, 5).Value + Cells(i, 6).Value + Cells(i, 7).Value + Cells(i, 8).Value + Cells(i, 9).Value + Cells(i, 10).Value
If x <> 100 And Cells(i, 5).Value <> "" Then
Cells(i, 5).EntireRow.Delete
i = i - 1
End If
Next i

End Sub

Sub Sequence()
Dim i As Integer
Dim x As Integer
Dim y As Integer
Dim a As Integer
Dim b As Integer

b = Cells(2, 3).Value

For i = 2 To Cells(2, 3).Value - 1
Cells(i, 1).Value = 0
Next i

For y = 0 To 100 Step Cells(8, 3).Value
a = 1

If y <> 0 Then
a = Int(100 / y)
If a > b Then
a = b
End If
End If

For x = 1 To a
Cells(i, 1).Value = y
i = i + 1
Next x

Next y

End Sub

Sub formu()
Dim lastrow As Long

lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp).Row
Range("D27:D" & lastrow).formula = "=E27&F27&G27&H27&I27&J27"
Range("C27:C" & lastrow).formula = "=IF(COUNTIF($D$27:$D$150000,D27)=1,FALSE,NOT(COUNTIF($D$2:D27,D27)=1))"
Range("$C$26:$C$150000").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="TRUE"
Range("C27:C150000").EntireRow.Delete
Sheet5.ShowAllData

End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this code is slow because of how often it touches the worksheet. There are both read and writes to worksheets in loops. There is also a recursive function that writes to the worksheet in a loop. I can't tell if you are doing this for ease of use or because you need to display the output. Avoid writing to the worksheet until output is required. Output all the data at once, instead of one cell at a time. See the example I give in the `Sequence` procedure.

I made the code have fully defined references so the system has to do less guessing and lookups. I doubt the performance change will be drastic.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub Combinations()
    Dim rRng As Range
    Dim p As Long

    Dim vElements As Variant
    Dim lrow As Long

    ActiveSheet.Range("A2:A100").Clear
    Sequence

    lrow = 25

    Set rRng = ActiveSheet.Range("A2", ActiveSheet.Range("A2").End(xlDown)) ' The set of numbers
    p = ActiveSheet.Range("C2").Value            ' How many are picked

    vElements = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(rRng), 1, 0)
    ReDim vresult(1 To p)
    ActiveSheet.Columns("E").Resize(, p + 5).Clear
    CombinationsNP vElements, p, vresult, lrow, 1, 1
    Delrow
    formu
    ActiveSheet.Range("C27:D15000").Clear
End Sub

Public Sub CombinationsNP(vElements As Variant, p As Long, vresult As Variant, lrow As Long, ByVal iElement As Long, iIndex As Long)
    Dim i As Long

    For i = iElement To UBound(vElements)
        vresult(iIndex) = vElements(i)
        If iIndex = p Then
            lrow = lrow + 1
            ActiveSheet.Range("E" & lrow + 1).Resize(, p) = vresult
        Else
            CombinationsNP vElements, p, vresult, lrow, i + 1, iIndex + 1
        End If
    Next i
End Sub

Public Sub Delrow()
    Dim lrow As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim x As Long

    With ActiveSheet
        lrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp).Row

        For i = 27 To lrow + 1
            x = .Cells(i, 5).Value + .Cells(i, 6).Value + .Cells(i, 7).Value + .Cells(i, 8).Value + .Cells(i, 9).Value + .Cells(i, 10).Value
            If x <> 100 And .Cells(i, 5).Value <> vbNullString Then
                .Cells(i, 5).EntireRow.Delete
                i = i - 1
            End If
        Next i
    End With
End Sub

Public Sub Sequence()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim x As Long
    Dim y As Long
    Dim a As Long
    Dim b As Long

    ' Example of setting all the cells at once
    With ActiveSheet
        b = .Cells(2, 3).Value
        .Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(b - 1, 1)).Value = 0
    End With

    For y = 0 To 100 Step ActiveSheet.Cells(8, 3).Value
        a = 1

        If y <> 0 Then
            a = Int(100 / y)
            If a > b Then
                a = b
            End If
        End If

        For x = 1 To a
            ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1).Value = y
            i = i + 1
        Next x
    Next y
End Sub

Public Sub formu()
    Dim lastrow As Long
    With ActiveSheet
        lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp).Row
        .Range("D27:D" & lastrow).Formula = "=E27&F27&G27&H27&I27&J27"
        .Range("C27:C" & lastrow).Formula = "=IF(COUNTIF($D$27:$D$150000,D27)=1,FALSE,NOT(COUNTIF($D$2:D27,D27)=1))"
        .Range("$C$26:$C$150000").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="TRUE"
        .Range("C27:C150000").EntireRow.Delete
    End With

    Sheet5.ShowAllData
End Sub
```